# How to handle PDO Fatal error when table is not exist?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to print the convenient error message(user understandable message ) instead of PDO system fatel error.

I have the following PDO statement, if that table not exist I want to print error message table is not exist.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cnf20;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
function getData($db) {
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_accessory_info1");
   return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

try {
  foreach(getData($db) as $row) {
    echo $row['part_no']; 
}
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $ex->getMessage(); 
}
```

Currently I'm getting this error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction
 in......on line 15
```

Instead of this I wanted to print user understandable error message like 'Please try again!'

Please support me! Thanks

Comment: `$db->rollBack();` is there a transaction at all? I don't see any.

Comment: There's no transaction and even nothing to roll back after a SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks bro! I'm new in PDO.

Comment: However, why would you want to query a non existent table?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul said, it's not clear why you would want to query a table that doesn't exist, but one way is to check for the existence of the table in MySQL before running your other statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
WHERE `table_schema` = 'database_name' AND `table_name` = 'table_name'
LIMIT 1;
```

This assumes the user connecting to the database has read access on `information_schema`.`tables`. Replace `'database_name'` and `'table_name'` with your values.